# Twig variables in slim frame work

Tags: php, variables, twig, slim

I want to pass data from my controller to the twig view.

this is my controller code:

```
    class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index($request, $response)
    {
        return $this->view->render($response, 'home.twig');
    }

    public function numbers($request, $response){

        return $this->view->render($response, 'home.twig', ['test' => '1221']);
    }
}
```

This is my home.twig code:

```
{% block content %}

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="content-wrapper container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="page-title">
                        <h1>Numbers for {{ test }} <small></small></h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
                            <li class="active">Data</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end .page title-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    {{  abs }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

The value 1221 that is set under test is not shown on the page when rendered.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you enable debug mode on twig?

Comment: Could you let us know about your application routes definitions? Are you sure `HomeController::numbers()` is being called and not `HomeController::index()`

Comment: Although this question is quite old: I just had the same issue. Using the twig var dumper with empty argument {{dump()}} saved my life